# Is it possible to execute Liquibase by 'SpringLiquibase.performUpdate' with more than one (or multi) change-logs

Tags: liquibase

I am a developer using Liquibase as DB migration tool.

Now I have more than one change-logs which need be executed one by one against a given DB schema.

My code looks like below:

```java
    void performUpdate(DataSource dataSource, String schema) throws LiquibaseException {
        for (String cl : changeLogList) {
            SpringLiquibase liquibase = createLiquibase();

            liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
            liquibase.setChangeLog(cl);
            liquibase.setDefaultSchema(schema);

            performUpdate(liquibase);
        }
    }

    void performUpdate(SpringLiquibase liquibase) throws LiquibaseException {
        liquibase.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
```

I just wonder whether **there is way to merge all these change-logs into one and executed all of them with one `SpringLiquibase` instance**.

There is a list for these change-logs. Which means that `SpringLiquibase' need be created for each change-log. Which will result in DB connection need be created and released for each change-log. Which may result in performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of liquibase [include](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/include.html) tag? The basic idea is to have one master changelog and include in it all child changelogs.

Comment: I know the '<include>' tag. But the situation which I encountered is that these changelogs are located in different jar dependencies (let's say A,B & C).
And these jars are not be included in each projects. (Some project may include A,B. Some project may just include C) So, if all these changelogs are included in a master change log with 'include'. It will result in some problem.

Comment: then maybe each project should know what it has to include and probably has it's own master changelog.